# Failed an audit for flagging a question asking for links to example code?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

As a new reviewer, I was just reviewing some First Posts when I came across this question:

[How detect NFC payment on app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627527/how-detect-nfc-payment-on-app)

After a quick look, I voted to close for being off-topic because the question is essentially asking for any example source code to do this.  In my understanding, I thought these type of posts that just asked for links to off-site resources should be closed?

Furthermore, the post had only attracted one answer which was also downvoted.  And going further, the user's 2nd question also looked quite broad.

Unfortunately, after voting to close, I received a message that I had just failed an audit for flagging to close when I should have marked it okay instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9143003

I've re-read the rules but I still don't understand why I should have voted this okay.  So I was just wondering if one of the more experienced reviewers on meta could please take a look and let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: It's the android tag. People there are very much upvote trigger happy.

Comment: IMHO it should be closed as a software recommendation or too broad as it is asking two different questions.  I have voted to close the question.

Comment: TGFTME (Thank God For The Meta Effect) it is closed, and has gotten nine downvotes thus far. Unfortunately, unless a mod intervenes, the failed audit won't be reversed.

Comment: It's ridiculous the original question was closed.  It's an utterly straightforward question .. in Android, how to detect if another app has used NFC pay.  Very straightforward, and good, question.

Comment: @JoeBlow: The question is closed for a reason. Such question tends to attracts link only answer, which becomes useless once the links are broken. This goes in contrary with the goal of having a repository of Q&A with lasting value.

Comment: You've simply read the question wrong, or something.  I edited the question to fix the clumsy English - go read it.  It's absolutely no different from asking how to open a window, how to use google maps, or how to bring up a menu.  It was just worded in a clumsy way - not everyone is a native English writer.

Comment: On a side note: I think you made the correct choice given the post that was presented to you in this case so I've lifted the review ban.

Comment: @JoeBlow your edits did more than just "fix the clumsy English", it changed the sense of the question from "where can I find an existing library or tool that does ..." to "how do I achieve ...". That is the difference between being on-topic or not, and the question got reopened because of that. Encouraging edits like is the entire point of the "on hold" process  - see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), which mentions that questions that are edited while 'on hold' and before becoming 'closed' automatically go to the Reopen Votes review queue.

Comment: You changed 90% of the post and then asked why we thought it was so off-topic. The question which has now been reopened is *not* the same question as was put on hold. The one that was put on hold was extremely off-topic.

Comment: Just yet another broken audit. SO seems to be determined to train us not to do them at all. It's working.

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback.  This has been most helpful.  @JoeBlow, I really like your edit but I didn't know we were allowed to make major edits like that.  Usually I edit posts for more minor things and don't change the entire structure of the post.  My takeaway from all this is that I should keep flagging as I have been.  Then me or someone else can make the required edits, and the post can be re-opened once it has been re-written to an acceptable standard.  Thanks to Jon Clements for lifting the review ban as well.

Comment: @Calcolat: It's commonplace where an existing post is _really, really_ bad. You're right that we wouldn't completely rewrite something that was already good enough, because to do so would be to cr@p all over its author. :)

Comment: Actually for the `android` tag even the original question was quite a good one. The first line asks for external reference, but the last para is where the meat lies. A good edit by @Joe has either way saved it, and I for one am quite interested to know the answer.

Comment: I think as RichardLM points out basically "the first line asked for external reference".  I would phrase it more as "only the first line happens to mention external reference, and it's a non-native writer anyway doing their best to conform to the style of the site".  The site has an overwhelming, clear-and-present problem where "naive editors" close/etc questions based on "hot words" (like "tool", as in my prolix example below): particularly given that, this QA is a great example of where one should, let's say, give the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score -7):

As IVC mentioned,

> "@JoeBlow your edits did more than just "fix the clumsy English", it
>   changed the sense of the question from "where can I find an existing
>   library or tool that does ..." to "how do I achieve ...". "

Now IVC, I simply disagree with you: the sense of the original question was, in my opinion, **precisely** what it is now....**exactly the same**.

This is a difficult issue. Highly idiomatic natural language, not to mention highly idiomatic technical slang-based English -- ***not to mention extremelye-non-native-English-speakers writing in highly idiomatic technical slang-based English*** -- is a tricky thing. A very tricky thing.

A simple example: now, when posting questions I completely ignore the ("idiotic") rule that there should be no preamble or signoffs. I always have a very short preamble (like, "maybe an expert knows this.." or "this has me  stumped!") and a very short signoff (like "thanks" or on answers "hope it helps") {Aside: indeed, these have ***extremely high content value***; humans draw spectacular amounts of information from social cues ranging from body language to what linguists call incidental "filler" language and sounds ... for example, I will end "hope it saves someone some typing" if the intent of my contribution is to provide greater detail (perhaps a code sample) on a simplish QA, or I will end "hope finally resolves" if it is one of those ongoing mysteries with no clear answer on the net.} Now, in the past, I often used the preamble ***"Here's a challenge..."*** simply meaning 'here's a particularly tough problem.' However, a couple non-native-English readers assumed I meant "here's a programming challenge", i.e. "here's a set-piece puzzle".  Doh!  So, of course I don't type that any more, as it's unclear.

Now, if you're a non-native-English writer reading this, you'll be thinking "WTF is this guy saying, 'here's a challenge' literally and specifically means you are introducing a programming puzzle." But that's totally wrong: it's just idiomatic (like saying "hell, how do I..." or "get this!" or "here's one..." or "this one's beyond me, guys and girls!") for "team, here's a particularly tough problem, I admit it's a bit hard for me, anyone have any ideas".

So that's a long, but, uh, informative and useful! example of the vagaries of "sense and feel" in writing on here.

There's a couple of issues,

1) In the example at hand, IVC, I actually believe the writer meant, precisely, what it now says.

2) There's a real danger in what I call **"naive keyword-recognition editing"** on this site.  So, in general there's a prohibition here against "asking for tools".  So - perhaps not unreasonably - if the word

## "tool"

happens to be in the text of a question, you get (no offence to anyone in this category) "naive" or "mechanistic" editors who flag it as "asking for a tool". (One of the reasons this happens is that some new users are "desperate" to suggest flags and edits.) This has happened to me (and probably most) users a couple times; I've asked a sophisticated, arcane question about CGLayer or something and happened to use the word "tool" or "package" - some joker has flagged it as "asking for a tool recommendation".  Result, I grind my teeth a bit and change the text.

3) **"@JoeBlow, I really like your edit** [you should read my stuff when I'm sober. or, you should just listen to my lyrics!] **but I didn't know we were allowed to make major edits like that."**

## Calcolat, you should make huge, enormous, edits all the time.

And that's that.

Indeed,

4) Let's say that my point (1) here is a bit off.  So, I'm claiming the writing was just a bit queer but, quite simply, (this whole thing sort of comes down to "one word"), IMO the guy was indeed wondering **"how**"** to do it ... but let's say I'm wrong, and the sense of the question was more leaning to "**what**" does this, "pass me a tool", "recommend a product!".  OK. I'm wrong. So, in that case, we're talking about: a very slight difference in a pointer to a spectrum of sense meanings, in, a messy, colloquial, idiomatic, forum writing, by someone who is knocking themselves out doing an awesome job trying to work in forum English!!  I mean .. WTF?! It's a case of...

## "Just click edit, and remove the offending word..."

Let's restate my point here. YES, you OCCASIONALLY see questions on the site that are like "Which word processing app should I buy?"  OK, those fall under the "no product recommendation" dictum.

BUT...

it's completely normal that in simply describing a "good" question you will touch on, or perhaps "sound like you are touching on" a more recommendation-like question.  I give an extreme example, where me simply using the word "tool" in an absolutely sophisticated (dare I say, charming, disarming and elegant) question results in such misunderstanding; here, we have a more extreme case where the wording is, anyway, shambolic {aside - so why try to draw exact, extremely narrow, shades of meaning out of it anyway?}, more idiomatic, more non-native, and more of a jumble, and has more "mention of" things like tools and packages.

But it comes down to CHANGING A COUPLE OF WORDS. Just edit it for goodness sake: in other words, just, if you will, give the question the benefit of the doubt, assume it means (as it were) "how" not "what", and edit a couple of words.

Comment: I got as far as your admission that you deliberately add noisy signatures and useless preambles, downvoted and stopped reading. Then I went back and read it again, and found that the downvote was still justified.

Comment: Answer is too long, but I like the basic gist - you fixed the garbage and rescued the question.

Comment: Hi Lightness - that's so funny .. do you write for TV or?